# My button is not re-rendered when using await/asnc

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and do a project in school. I am trying to play the audio from url by using react-native-audio-recorder-player and await/aysnc function. Everything is oke until when i want to show the loader (Activity Indicator) while user is waiting for the audio is downloaded from url

My solution is create the isLoading in state, when user click on the button, in the onPress function i will setState for isLoading is true and add a callback for that setState to call another async function. In that async function i will use await to get the audio from url and then when the respone will be received i will setState for isLoading is true. Howerver, my component is not re-rendered even isLoading state is true. I have checked very carefully on componentWillUpdate, Render, componentDidUpdate. My isLoading state works fine exepting my component. Below is my code, sorry for my bad English. Thanks !

```
    <View style={styles.parentViewStyle}
          <Button
            title='Click on me'
            onPress={()=>{     
              //set state for isloading true and call async function 
              this.setState({isLoading:true},()=>{this.play()
              });}}
          />
          //this text depends on the isLoading state.
          <Text>
            {this.state.isLoading?'is loading':'play'}
          </Text>
        </View>
```

```
     play=async()=>{
    console.log(this.state.isLoading);
    //isLoading here is true but my text shows 'playing'
    await sounder.startPlayer("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");
    this.setState({isLoading:false});
  }
```

Comment: Does the song ever start playing? You should also use the await like this: ```const result = await this.sounder.startPlayer("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");``` and add a ```return;``` at the end of your play function.

Comment: Yes, i have tried it first because it is the suggestion in library documentation but still doesn't work. The song still plays after 20 secs. The strange thing is that if i fetch some api such as await fetch('api.github.com');, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem should be that you put a function in a anonyme state and never launch it. To launch the `play()` function you can do like this:

```
this.setState({isLoading:true});
this.play();
```

The second problem is that `await` just don't... wait until the end of `sounder.startPlayer()`. You can see this by doing:

```
console.log('START');
await sounder.startPlayer("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");
console.log('END');
```

I don't know why await don't work... I hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have tried it and got no result. If i wrote like this, it will run the play func before running componentWillupdate, so isLoading the console.log('start); is false.